# DOM in React is not updated properly set component dynamically

Tags: reactjs

In react seems like DOM is not updating
    Lets say on click of a checkbox lets say id is **checkbox1** I want to add
    another checkbox lets say id **Checkbox2** should be checked as well
    so

```
Checkbox id="checkbox1" onClick={this.handleChange.bind(this)} 
handleChange(){
    document.getElementById(checkbox2).checked=true;
}
```

while debug I can see below line executed

```
document.getElementById(checkbox2).checked=true;
```

But DOM is not updating, checked it is working with JavaScript some issue with react

Comment: It will be great if you share code of render method.

Comment: handleCheck: function() {
    document.getElementById("chk2").checked=true;
  },
  
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" onChange={this.handleCheck} />
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" onChange={this.handleCheck} />
      
      </div>
    );
  }
});

Comment: As react working principle you have to change component's state property to render dom again. If not dom is not rerendered.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the react core principles update DOM using state only. It is mainly diffing concept to update virtual DOM. Below code snippet will work.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked1: false,
      checked2: false
    }

  }

  handleCheck = () => {
    this.setState({ checked2: !this.state.checked2 });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" onChange={this.handleCheck} checked={this.state.checked1} />
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" onChange={this.handleCheck} checked={this.state.checked2} />

      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```